# How to deserialize a type with a generic parameter from XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, generics, serialization

I have a class that contains a generic parameter and is marked as [Serializable]. Simplified version of this is:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class MySerializableClass<T> where T : IMyInterface<T>
{
    public T MyType;    
}

public interface IMyInterface<out T>
{   
   T Clone();
   //..some other methods
}

[Serializable]
public class TypeA : IMyInterface<TypeA>
{
    public TypeA Clone()
    {
        return new TypeA();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class TypeB : IMyInterface<TypeB>
{
    public TypeB Clone()
    {
        return new TypeB();
    }   
}
```

I want to deserialize an instance of this class from XML.

For example, if I wanted to deserialize an instance which contains an instance of TypeA then the XML would be along the following lines:

```
<MyRoot>
    <MySerializableClass>
    ...
    ...
    </MySerializableClass>
    <MyTypeA>
    ...
    ...
    </MyTypeA>
<MyRoot>
```

Since I wasn't sure how to to specify the correct type to be deserialized I experimented with various tags like [XmlInclude] and [XmlRoot] without success. I continually received exceptions due to an unrecognized element.

While debugging I observed that there was an expected element of type 'MySerializableClassOfTypeA' or 'MySerializableClassOfTypeB' depending on which XML file I was deserializing. I changed my Xml to the following and can now successfully deserialize.

```
<MyRoot>
    <MySerializableClassOfTypeA>
    ...
    ...
    </MySerializableClassOfTypeA>
    <MyTypeA>
    ...
    ...
    </MyTypeA>
<MyRoot>
```

However I only found this solution by chance; I can't find it documented anywhere. I would like to know if this the correct/only way to deserialize an XML file where the type to be deserialized contains a generic parameter?

Comment: What type would you like to deserialize `<MySerializableClass>` to? `MySerializableClass<int>`, `MySerializableClass<object>` or `MySerializableClass<SqlConnection>`? A human couldn't guess the correct answer. The deserializer can't decide by itself unless you tell it somehow the *concrete* type you want it to create

Comment: This sounds like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have problem X and think Y is the solution so you ask about Y when you run into problems. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? A generic type can't be instantiated so it makes no sense to try to deserialize XML to a generic type. Do you have perhaps issues with inheritance or covariance in your DTOs?

Comment: I don't expect the deserializer to guess; I am simply asking about the behaviour whereby the XMLElement name is changed under the hood to include the '..OfType..' part. I don't find this documented anywhere and discovered it only through debugging. My question is whether this is the correct way to do this serialization or whether there is some other mechanism which doesn't involve change the XMLElement name

Comment: Add some sample data to your classes and then save Serialized Results to a file.  The you will know the correct format for XML.

Comment: Further, the 'actual problem' in this case is that I have two assemblies which share an almost identical configuration file. I want to re-use the type used to deserialise this config from XML. However there is a minor difference in that the type of a particular property in the config is different for each assembly. Hence the desire to use a generic parameter which can be of either type.

Comment: This isn't a minor difference. A generic type does *not* imply any inheritance relation between its concrete types. There is no "is-a" relationship between them. For the same reason, the serializer's behavior makes sense. When faced with an initialized generic type instance, it has to decide on a *concrete* name. Just as the debugger displays `MyClass'1` or `MyClass'int`, the serializer decides to use `MyClassOfTypeString`. Even for XML, the schemas of the two files (if they had any) would be different and the two documents would be considered incompatible